# Async sockets always reading 0 bytes when sending a lot of packets at once

Tags: c#, multithreading, sockets

I've researched this many hours and tried a lot of different things to figure this out but I'm stuck. I'm trying to create an asynchronous socket that will be access from multiple threads. It tends to run okay until I have a few threads that are trying to send close to the same time. There's no error with sending, the only issue is when EndReceive() tries to read the data, it returns 0 bytes and the socket error is "success". I've read this means it was a graceful shutdown and the server has no more data to send but the type of server I'm connecting to should never have sent all data, it's not that type of server. There should always be data to be read and it shouldn't close.

The threads I used to send where a few System.Threading.Timers but I read they aren't exactly thread safe. I also tried with System.Timers.Timer but it was the same result. I've also tried using only 1 thread to send a lot of packets at once, sleeping for 100ms between, and I'll get the same result.

For receiving the code is below. For sending, I've tried just regular blocking Send and also BeginSend and it didn't make a difference.

```
void Receive()
    {
        try
        {
            if (_datacb == null)
                _datacb = new AsyncCallback(OnRecvData);

            byte[] buffer = new byte[FBufferSize];
            FSocket.BeginReceive(buffer, 0, FBufferSize, SocketFlags.None, _datacb, buffer);
        }
        catch (SocketException ex)
        {
            OnSocketError(ex);
        }
    }

    void OnRecvData(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        try
        {
            SocketError err;
            int bytesRead = FSocket.EndReceive(ar, out err);

            if (bytesRead == 0)
            {
                throw new SocketException();
            }

            byte[] buffer = ar.AsyncState as byte[];
            FReceived.AddBytes(buffer, bytesRead);
            ByteBuffer message = FReceived.GetNextMessage();
            while (message != null)
            {
                Process(message);
                message = FReceived.GetNextMessage();
            }
        }
        catch (SocketException ex)
        {
            OnSocketError(ex);
        }

        Receive();
    }
```

I thought it could be the server that is just shutting down the socket for sending too fast, but I actually have a blocking version I made in VS2008 and I was able to use 50 different timers that sent 1 packet each second and I didn't get disconnected. I tried almost the same code in VS2010 and bytesRead was 0. I also tried the asyc socket code in VS2008 just to see if something weird was going on but in VS2008 it still gives me bytesRead == 0. For the blocking code that doesn't disconnect me:

```
tcpClient = new TcpClient(host, 443);
networkStream = tcpClient.GetStream();
mReader = new BinaryReader(networkStream);
mWriter = new BinaryWriter(networkStream);
receiveMessage = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ReceiveMessages));
receiveMessage.Start();

private void ReceiveMessages()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            if ((tcpClient != null) && (tcpClient.Connected))
            {
                if (tcpClient.Available >= 4)
                {
                    if (!isConnected) isConnected = true;

                    try
                    {
                        ByteBuffer message = new ByteBuffer();
                        message.AddBytes(mReader.ReadBytes(4));
                        int mSize = message.ReadInt();
                        message.AddBytes(mReader.ReadBytes(mSize - 4));
                        processor.Process(message);
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        Print("Recv Msg: " + ex.Message);
                    }
                }

                Thread.Sleep(1);
            }
}
```

Sending:

```
mWriter.Write(send);
mWriter.Flush();
```

Not too happy with it because it uses a lot of CPU. I tried other ways to do blocking sockets like this without using as much CPU but they tend to disconnect as well.

Comment: Please don't prefix your titles with "C#" and such. That's what the tags are for.

Comment: Is there any chance this relates to the fact that you're calling Receive even if there is an exception? The Receive should be at the end of the "try", not after the "catch", IMO

Comment: Is the blocking version actually blocking?  IIRC, 'tcpClient.Available' does not block until 4 bytes are available - so you waste most time on a latency-inducing, CPU-wasting sleep(1) loop.

Comment: I let it call Receive even with the exception just to ignore the 0 bytes read issue. It will just keep receiving 0 bytes until I get Connection Aborted by host machine and it will close anyways. So the end result would still be a closed socket.

Comment: I meant that it was blocking when there's enough data available. So yeah it is using most of the CPU on sleep(1) but it only ever became an issue when I opened a lot of connections. It's the main reason I'd like to switch to async.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently it had nothing to do with the actual sending, but rather the data that was being sent. The server expected a certain fingerprint to be sent with each packet, a type of encryption. Each time you get the fingerprint, you have to adjust a value. I was doing a thread lock on the actual send, but it needed to be locked on the part where it also calculated the fingerprint. Some packets were sent with wrong fingerprints because they got calculated out of order so the server disconnected in that manner.

I probably should have mentioned that in my question but I didn't think it was relevant.

Answer (score 0):

Sockets are not thread safe. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

You should synchronize your access to your socket, or let one thread handle all of it (which I think is cleaner, and will also lead to easier debugging).

Comment: If you look, the next receive is triggered by the end of the one before; that is perfectly normal and safe

Comment: I believe the receiving is safe that way. As far as sending, I've attempted to make it safe by locking on an object. It didn't help so I tried to make sure only 1 thread is accessing Send() by using a BlockingCollection that threads could add a packet to. I used a System.Timers.Timer to check the collection every so often, changing from 10ms to 100ms. I still run into the same issue with it reading 0 bytes and eventually disconnecting.

Answer (score 0):

Socket **can** read 0 bytes. This is normal. What you have to do is to **read again until you get the full data packet**. This is a common mistake when people expect the socket to read the same amounts of bytes as server had send it. Yes, this often workouts. But indeed the data can get fragmented and you'll get just data chunks. So, your code should be ready to assemble data chunks from the socket because data fragmentation is imminent.